# How to regenerate components, plugins, etc... for ionic framework app/project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, frameworks, ionic-framework

I moved my ionic app's project copying not all the folders but these ones: app, hooks, platforms, plugins, resources, test and www and the files that are outside of this folders, including the Gruntfile.js and config.xml.
Well, I heard there's a way to regenerate the app through the Gruntfile.js or an a file of this, so the project is prepared like it was in my past location (other PC).
Let me thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you saved your state then you can restore it using ionic or cordova

```
ionic state  ..........  Saves or restores state of your Ionic Application using the
                         package.json file
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron! this was it! `ionic state restore` and works perfect :)